# How to create a full-screen jssor slider that maximizes but does not crop images?

Tags: jssor

I am trying to create a slider that fills the entire screen (desktop and mobile) with the largest possible scaled image -- *without* cropping.  In other words, I want to view a set of photos in their entirely, and have each of them sized to fill all available space without cropping.  I expect to see "gray bars" on two sides of most images, unless it happens to fit the screen exactly.

Here's what I have so far:

Start with https://www.jssor.com/demos/full-window-for-pc.slider

1. click Edit this Slider
2. Upload two images with varying aspect ratios: one really wide, and one portrait shaped (look in /ajssd).
3. Choose Layout > Fill Mode > Contain
4. Choose Layout > Bleeding > 0
5. Choose Layout > Scale To > Full Window (Constrain Mode)

This is close but not quite.  The image that is wide has padding on all four sides, which means it is not rendering as large as possible.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?  It needs to work on Desktop and Mobile, and handle browser resizes and orientation changes.

Comment: You are right, I noticed there is white space.

Answer (score 0):

6. Set Layout > Max Width > 3000
7. Set Layout > Max Height > 3000

Comment: Yes, I have that.  In the editor, the defaults for Max Width and Max Height are both 3000.  I still see a lot of whitespace around the images.  It seems like what's happening is this: JSSOR uses the "slide width/height" (e.g. 960 x 640) to, in effect, allocate the biggest possible rectangle with that aspect ratio in the container.  Then it essentially draws all images inside that rectangle.  An image with a "wider" aspect ratio will have whitespace on all four sides because it can't expand "wider" than the originally-allocated rectangle.  ScaleSize() doesn't solve it.

Comment: Exactly. As workaround, you can set the original size at ratio of mean value of your images instead of 960 x 640. It will make your slider look better. And we will look for solution.